# Android AddOnPreDrawListener not getting content height

Tags: java, android

My AddOnPreDrawListener method isn't getting the height of the webview?

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserverTop = topContent.getViewTreeObserver();

    viewTreeObserverTop.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int topHeight = topContent.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (topHeight != 0) {
                    RelativeLayout instructions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.info_layout);
                    instructions.post(mAddTabletMargin);
                }
                topContent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(
                        this);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Could anyone suggest why or any other methods I could use to get the height?

Comment: try to Log.d both getHeight and getMeasuredHeight

Comment: it always returns 0 on tablets, and on smaller phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) it works perfectly? could it be something to do with the verison of android?

Answer (score 0):

could get view height by this:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageFrameLayout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
       vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() { 
       public boolean onPreDraw() { 
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams para=null;
        para = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();  
        para.width = (int) ((imageFrameLayout.getMeasuredHeight())*0.75); 
       return true; 
       } 
       });
```